# How can we add new field in the column contain Expression related to different fields?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

Below are sample table data in ssrs report,

```
ValueFor                  FirstHr    SecondHr    ThirdHr

Total Contacts                128      101         79

Abandons                       8       10           4
```

**ValueFor,1Hrs,2Hrs and 3Hrs** **are columns**
Above,I need to add "Contacts Handled"  filed under the "**ValueFor**" Column,its values depend on the same column in the different fields?

Contacts Handled=Total Contacts/Abandons

My Result is ,

```
      ValueFor                  FirstHr    SecondHr    ThirdHr

     Total Contacts                128      101         79

     Abandons                       8       10           4

    Contacts Handled                 16     10.1       19.75
```

How can I write Expression in **FirstHr,SecondHr and ThirdHr**  columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an expression like:

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Total Contacts", Fields!MyValue.Value, Nothing))
  / Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Abandons", Fields!MyValue.Value, Nothing))
```

Using a conditional `Sum` as above you can look at all records in a particular Scope but only consider the ones that fulfill that particular criterion - by combining two you can get your required result.

**Edit after comment**

With your data:

[image]

I have a simple table:

[image]

Note that the expressions are all in the table footer row.

The expressions are:

**FirstHr**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Total Contacts", Fields!FirstHr.Value, Nothing))
  / Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Abandons", Fields!FirstHr.Value, Nothing))
```

**SecondHr**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Total Contacts", Fields!SecondHr.Value, Nothing))
  / Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Abandons", Fields!SecondHr.Value, Nothing))
```

**ThirdHr**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Total Contacts", Fields!ThirdHr.Value, Nothing))
  / Sum(IIf(Fields!ValueFor.Value = "Abandons", Fields!ThirdHr.Value, Nothing))
```

Works fine for that dataset:

[image]

Comment: Hi Preston, When i did like above but am getting 0 Value,please help me to give exact expression.

Comment: You need to give more details on your data. For example, you have a column called `1Hrs` but this cannot exist in SSRS - you can't have a column that starts with a number. Create a SQL Fiddle at sqlfiddle.com that shows a sample dataset with appropriate data, column names and data types.

Comment: Preston please consider   FirstHr SecondHr and ThirdHr instead of 1hrs ,2hrs and 3hrs.Actually i showed like front end,please need your help..

Comment: @Preston,Thanks for nice replied by example,its nicely worked for me.